# How does Microsoft Windows Group Policy relate to programming?

Tags: design-patterns, group-policy

Is it inheritance?  Is it the decorator pattern?  The Composite Pattern?  Strategy Pattern?  Something else?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming?

Comment: It does too! Considering GP was programmed.  If GP were tree or grass then it wouldn't be software; but you know what? It is software.